# Mixing Python web platforms PHP, e.g. - Mediawiki, Wordpress, etc

Tags: php, python, wordpress, mediawiki, mod-wsgi

Is anyone developing application integrated with Mediawiki - using Django or other Python web development platforms using mod_wsgi?

Would be very interested to find out what has been done in this direction and maybe there is some code available for re-use. (I've started creating wiki extensions working with MW database in python whose output is injected via Apache's include virtual directive. it works ok, but a bit slow so far - maybe I can optimize it though)

Basically I would like to have certain parts of displayed wiki pages be prepared with python.

Has anyone reproduced common MW skins in python templates?

**edit:** found this nice video showing how PyCon site does just that (not with MW though) - using custom template loader

http://showmedo.com/videos/video?name=pythonNapleonePyConTech2&fromSeriesID=54

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are so many different ways to do this.

- You can make a mediawiki skin that uses iframes and inserts things from a Python server.
- You can write a python app that accesses mediawikis data somehow and outputs it.
- You can put a Python server in front that extracts the content from mediawiki and put's it into a page that is otherwise generated from Python.
- You can use deliverence to skin mediawiki, and use it's pyref functionality to call pythonscripts and insert that into the skin (I think, I haven't done that myself).

Which way is best for you completely depends.

Comment: It's mentioned in the deliverence docs. http://openplans.org/projects/deliverance

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use Mediawiki HTTP based API?  Loose coupling is great.